# Sing with a piano

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I'm trying to figure out what 'sing with a piano' means. Does this always mean 'someone sings while he/she is playing the piano'? Is it possible to say 'He sang with his brother's piano'(He sang while his brother was playing the piano)? Also, I wonder about the difference between 'He sang with a piano' and 'He sang to the piano'. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you trying to figure this out? Did you come across it in real life somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that "sing with a piano" is actually short for "sing with a piano accompaniment" and it doesn't matter whether the singer plays the piano or whether someone else plays the phrase is the same. The same thing also applies to singing with a guitar, mandolin, bazouki etc. What you can't do, however, is sing with a wind instrument unless someone else is playing it because you can't sing and blow at the same time. However people can and do "sing with a flute" or "sing with a saxophone" when someone else is playing

Comment: This seems a very generous interpretation. Have you ever encountered the specific construction?